# Problema al unir dos csv en pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

Necesito unir 3 csv en pyspark por medio de dataframes en **google colab**, al unir los dos primeros csv me salta un error, dejo el código en la siguiente linea:

```
onf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('Dataframe')
sc = SparkContext( conf=conf )

from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

dfBanco = sqlContext.read.format('csv').option('header', True).option('inferSchema', True).load(ruta + '/Data_Banco.csv', sep=',')
dfCajero = sqlContext.read.format('csv').option('header', True).option('inferSchema', True).load(ruta + '/Data_Cajero.csv', sep=',')
dfSucursal = sqlContext.read.format('csv').option('header', True).option('inferSchema', True).load(ruta + '/Data_Sucursal.csv', sep=',')
```

al realizar el join me salta un error

```
datosBancoCajero = dfBanco.join(dfCajero, how='inner', on=['ID_Cajero'])
datosBancoCajero.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-c6886e1f5282> in <module>
----> 1 datosBancoCajero = dfBanco.join(dfCajero, how='inner', on=['ID_Cajero'])
      2 datosBancoCajero.show()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    194                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    195                 # JVM exception message.
--> 196                 raise converted from None
    197             else:
    198                 raise

AnalysisException: USING column `ID_Cajero` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [Sucursal, Cajero, ID_Transaccion, Transaccion, Tiempo_Servicio_seg, Satisfaccion, Monto]
```

[image: Error]

Comment: gracias por la observacion

Comment: El error es porque en el `dataframe` que usas como base (`dfBanco`) no existe la columna "ID_CAJERO". Según la información del error la columna se llama "Cajero".